# What happens when one calls a setter/getter on a property that has not been alloc+init'ed?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've got a simple question about objective-c.

I've been taught to lazily instantiate my properties by synthesizing them and then overriding the getter in the following manner.

```
-(SomeClass *)someProperty {
    if ( !_someProperty )
        _someProperty = [[SomeClass alloc] init ]
    return _someProperty
}
```

What happens when I don't do this? I ask this because I have properties that are not allocated & instantiated in this manner and they seem (maybe not) to behave just fine.

My only guess is that if a property is unallocated & instantiated it will be left as nil; in which case messaging nil would do nothing. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, messaging nil is just fine. You don't have to override any getters to lazily initialize your properties. See this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables are automatically set to `nil` (or `0` for primitive types) when the object is created, so you don't have to worry about sending messages to uninitialized properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, if you try to send a message to nil nothing is going to happen. That is the main point to allocate it and initialize it. Allocating just gives the property a place in memory.